# Сохранение выбранных столбцов из DataGrid в формат Excel (C#/WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

В DataGrid приходят набор данных, не все данные имеют одинаковый набор столбцов и их порядок. Данные в DataGrid появляется вручную, не через ItemSource и DataContext.
Выбор столбцов в DataGrid проходит посредством CheckBox'ов.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="CheckBoxes"/>
<DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="CsvGrid" ColumnWidth="*" MouseDoubleClick="CsvGrid_OnMouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding csvTable}"/>
```

CheckBox'ы создаются в коде и добавляются в StackPanel:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{
    CheckBox _checks = new CheckBox();
    _checks.Tag = fileDataField[i];
    _checks.Content = fileDataField[i];
    CheckBoxes.Children.Add(_checks);
}
```

Дальше хочу сохранить именно те столбцы которые отмеченные в CheckBox'е:

```
CsvGrid.SelectAllCells(); // беру все столбцы
foreach (var checkBox in CheckBoxes.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked == true))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < CsvGrid.SelectedCells.Count; i++)
    {
        if(checkBox.Tag != CsvGrid.Columns[i].Header) //Как удалить лишние ???
    }
}
CsvGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, CsvGrid);
String result = (string) Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
CsvGrid.UnselectAllCells();

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Document";
saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xls";
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel|*.xls|Excel 2010|*.xlsx|CSV files (*.csv)|*.CSV";
saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true) File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, result.Replace(',', ' '));
MessageBox.Show("File created!");
```

Как мне в foreach из выборки:

> CsvGrid.SelectAllCells();

удалить не нужные столбцы?

Comment: Таким образом вы выбираете какие столбцы с данными попадают в файл? Вы хотите выбрать сами столбцы или столбцы с данными?Вы хотите с помощью foreach выбрать необходимые вам столбцы из datagrid? 

Т.е кого "их" вы хотите выбрать через foreach?

Comment: @Arantler Да, я хочу выбрать столбцы с данными через foreach. Именно те столбцы которые отмеченные в чекбохе.

Comment: Обновил вопрос!

Comment: лучше так. Данные в DataGrid появляется вручную, не через ItemSource и DataContext

Comment: Да, появляется вручную.

Comment: в смысле напишите это. Так намного понятнее о чем речь(точнее вообще становится понятно)

Comment: В коде нет никакого преобразования в "формат Excel". Вы пишете в файл просто текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CsvGrid.Items.Refresh();
CsvGrid.UpdateLayout();

for (int i = 0; i < CsvGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (var checkBox in CheckBoxes.Children.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.IsChecked == true))
    {
        if (CsvGrid.Columns[i].Header.ToString() == checkBox.Tag.ToString()) CsvGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
     }
}

CsvGrid.SelectAllCells();
CsvGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, CsvGrid);
String result = (string) Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
CsvGrid.UnselectAllCells();

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Document";
saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xls";
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel|*.xls|Excel 2010|*.xlsx|CSV files (*.csv)|*.CSV";
saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, result.Replace(',', ' '));
    MessageBox.Show("File created!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, т.к у вас нет изначальной коллекции объектов(ItemSource), а данные добавляются вручную, то вам нужно превратить ваш DataGrid в DataTable.

Делается это вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109009/how-to-make-a-datatable-from-datagridview-without-any-datasource)

Или сделать вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10604476/6762483)

Второе скорее всего не сработает(ибо он по идее должны быть пустым, хотя я не уверен. Пробуйте). В любом случае способ при создании DataTable в первой ссылке(перебор Rows, а далее в этом Row Column по индексу) должен сработать.

Просто пройтись по столбцам **не получится**. Если это и возможно, то через составление DataTable(вторая ссылка)(там просто по индексам строка\столбец можно все выбрать, как в Excel через vba( Cells[i,y])).

В итоге с помощью двух foreach вы получите нужные вам данные. выглядить это будет это примерно так

```
var column1 = new List<string>();
var column2 = new List<string>();
var listColumn= new List<List<string>>();
listColumn.Add(column1);
listColumn.Add(column2);

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
   foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
   {
      listColumn[cell.ColumnIndex].Add(cell.Value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Нужно придумать как выбрать столбцы через foreach. Да все данные динамическое. Сохранение уже реализовано частично. Все что вы расписали я уже пробовал... Вы код смотрели?

Comment: Код я смотрел. Тогда вам подходит последний вариант. Вы берете примерно так 

foreach(var столбец in checkboxes)
{// То, где у вас хранятеся данные
//Столбец выбирается тем же if/switch
 dataContext.Select(x => x.Столбец);
}

Comment: Как раз это у меня уже и написано)) Посмотрите) Там уже выбирается готовый список из отмеченных чекбоксов...

Comment: @MiT да, теперь вижу. Как понимаю вам не нравится подобный вариант и вы хотите сделать это красиво, так? Красиво скорее всего не будет, это C# и с динамикой не бывает просто в C#(хоть вроде и движется немного в ту сторону). В вашем случае делать то, что я говорил, только через Reflection(т.е мы создаем динамические Checkbox, далее проходясь по коллекциям в цикле через Reflection вытаскиваем поля по имени в string и отсеиваем).

Comment: @MiT как кстати тогда у вас данные в DataGrid попадают, если структура изначально не известна?

Comment: Изначально файл парситься и конвертирует в DataGrid. Как раз мне нравиться этот способ, но я его не могу доделать... Можно пример кода с Reflection увидеть?

Comment: @MiT тогда вам не подойдет то, что я предлагал. Укажите на всякий случай в вопросе как именно данные попадают в DataGrid, это важно(парсятся. т.е в DataGrid у вас значения, а не коллекция из ObservalableObject<object>. Учитывая то, как к вам попадают данные,моими способами воспользоваться вы не можете(ибо не над чем). Я щас исправлю ответ тогда

Comment: Обновил вопрос!

Comment: @MiT обновил ответ. Это похоже на то, что вы хотели? Таким образом у вас получится List<List<string>> т.е список со столбцами в виде списков.

Comment: Мне не нужно список со столбцами, мне нужно 1) выбрать столбцы 2) записать их в файл. и 1 и 2 пункт уже готовы. Через `CsvGrid.SelectAllCells();` я получаю все столбцы, мне осталось удалить лишние столбцы. Вот в чем вопрос...

Comment: @MiT теперь понятно, что вы хотите. Но вы ведь моим способом решаете эту задачу более подходящими средствами. Просто добавить условия и пройтись по таблице. В получите только те столбцы, которые вам нужны. Щас подумаю тогда, как из вашего варианта убрать не нужные столбцы.

Comment: @MiT я перечитал обновленный вопрос и задам этот вопрос еще раз. Вы хотите столбцы с данными или только Header этих столбцов? И чек боксами вы просто убираете Header? Если первое, то мой вариант с условиями работает. Если второе, то тогда не понимаю что вы хотите сделать. Ибо дополнительный код говорит, что как будто у вас в SelectedAllCells только Header столбцов или что-то подобное.